# SKBitmap.Decode() always returns null when trying to decode image file

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to decode an image file using the SKBitmap.Decode() method in my SkiaSharp application, but the bitmap2 object is always null. I have checked that the file exists and is readable, and the file format is JPEG, which is supported by SkiaSharp. I have also tried logging the path to the image file and the error message, but there are no errors being reported.

I am not sure what is causing the problem. I have tried everything I can think of, but I am still not able to get the image to decode successfully.

Additional information:

I am using the latest version of SkiaSharp (4.7.1).
I am working on a Xamarin Forms application.
I am using the SKImageInfo and SKPaint classes to render the decoded image to a SKCanvas.
I would appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: [Quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skbitmap.decode?view=skiasharp-2.88): *Returns: The decoded bitmap, or null on error*.  It is not happy about the file.

Comment: Where is the relevant code?  Where is the image located?  Is it included in the project bundle, or generated at runtime?  If it's in the bundle, what is it's build action?

Comment: @Jason It's not in project It is from hard disk, Also here is the code: `SKBitmap bitmap2 = SKBitmap.Decode("C:/Users/user/Pictures/icon (1).jpg");`.

Comment: An Android or iOS app cannot access files on the PC's file system.   There is no `c:\` drive on a mobile device

Comment: You can put the image in the device and try to read it.